# Check configurations applied for nginx ingress controller on a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

I have setup nginx ingress controller configurations under the data property as shown in the below yaml file.

1. I would like to know is this the correct way to set nginx configurations instead of providing a nginx.conf file.
2. Secondly I would like to find out whether the provided configurations are set. To find whether the new configurations are applied, should I exec into the pod and run `nginx -T` or is there any other way to find it?

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  worker-processes: "24"
  worker-connections: "100000"
  worker-rlimit-nofile: "102400"
  worker-cpu-affinity: "auto 111111111111111111111111"
  keepalive: "200"
  main-template: | 
   user nginx;
   worker_processes  {{.WorkerProcesses}};
   {{- if .WorkerRlimitNofile}}
   worker_rlimit_nofile {{.WorkerRlimitNofile}};{{end}}
   {{- if .WorkerCPUAffinity}}
   worker_cpu_affinity {{.WorkerCPUAffinity}};{{end}}
   {{- if .WorkerShutdownTimeout}}
   worker_shutdown_timeout {{.WorkerShutdownTimeout}};{{end}}
   daemon off;

   error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log {{.ErrorLogLevel}};
   pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

   {{- if .MainSnippets}}
   {{range $value := .MainSnippets}}
   {{$value}}{{end}}
   {{- end}}

   events {
       worker_connections  {{.WorkerConnections}};
   }

   http {
       include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type  application/octet-stream;
       
       ...
      

       sendfile        on;
       access_log  off;
       tcp_nopush  on;
       tcp_nodelay on;

       keepalive_timeout  315;
       keepalive_requests 10000000;

       #gzip  on;   
        ...
   }

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways how to install `NGINX Ingress Controller`, however they depends on environments they are deploying on.
For example for minikube:

**minikube**

For standard usage:

`minikube addons enable ingress`

To check if the ingress controller pods have started, run the following command:

`$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx \ -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx --watch`

You can use **helm** (but only `v3`):

`NGINX Ingress controller` can be installed via  [Helm](https://helm.sh/)  using the chart from the project repository. To install the chart with the release name  `ingress-nginx`:

```
$ helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
$ helm repo update
$ helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Then try to detect installed version:

`POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version`

However most common way is to install the NGINX Ingress Controller in your Kubernetes cluster using Kubernetes manifests and then modify nginx-config.yaml

**Summing up:** you have to to modify nginx.conf file. You are providing clear specification and then easily you can debug it.

Read more: [nginx-ingress-controller-installation-manifest](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/), [nginx-ingress-controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Even while troubleshooting you have examples to check `nginx.conf` file.
To check Ingress Controller you can for example:

- **check the Ingress Resource Events**

  ```
  $ kubectl get ing -n <namespace-of-ingress-resource> NAME 
  $ kubectl describe ing <ingress-resource-name> -n <namespace-of-ingress-resource>
  ```
- **check the Ingress Controller Logs**

  ```
    $ kubectl get pods -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> 
    $ kubectl logs -n <namespace> nginx-ingress-controller
  ```
- **check the Nginx Configuration**

  ```
     $ kubectl get pods -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller>   
     $ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> nginx-ingress-controller -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  ```
- **check if used Services Exist**

  ```
    $ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
  ```

See more: [ingress-troubleshooting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/).